# Light switch buzzing

Tags: lighting

We've moved into a new home and fitted some metal switches, weirdly on the downstairs set of lights when you run your finger along the face or touch your ear to the socket there is a small buzz.

However, this doesn't happen on the upstairs sockets.

Having looked there is an earth to the backbox and then an earth from that to the earth terminal of the switch, even with all those in the buzzing still occurs?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. What kind of lights and switches are these? Where in the world are you? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: So this new construction or just new to you? In either case it is possible you have a switch with bad contacts, it happens.  Some electronic switches also can be noisy,  because of the cheap components can emit a audible buzz.

Comment: @EdBeal New to us, it does it on all the switches downstairs, even if we swap a random one out. Interestingly if your finger is stationary, no buzz. If you move your finger around that's when it buzzes?

Comment: Can you get us a photo of the connections & switch model. Also is the downstairs on a sub panel not the main? To me it sounds like electronic switches that require a ground. I have seen some issues but mostly with non UL listed “made in china” not legal for use in the US but available online. I have also seen it with a led comparable that required a ground and no ground provided (tied to neutral).

Comment: @EdBeal Switches are these https://www.electricalcounter.co.uk/products/Switches+%26+Sockets/Selectric/5M+Screwed/Black+Nickel/Black+Nickel+%26+Black+Screwed+Slim+1+Gang+2+Way+Plate+Switch+10A/807049537 the downstairs circuit is on it's own breaker and each of the switches are earthed (as are the back plates). It's a head scratcher!

Comment: Your earthing sounds good I went to the web site. I did not see the certification that I know I saw one but I don’t know your codes . My only guess is it is electronic. And your body is acting like an antenna not sure why it would do it there and not in other locations.